# Printing divs and svgs shifts their alignment (JointJs)

Tags: javascript, html, printing, position, jointjs

So I have a small issue with printing a selected div of my web application, which contains divs and svg-Elements.

I am using JointJs for a diagram-building-app, where i use the underlying jointjs models, which is an svg containing graphs for positioning and connections and an added HtmlView to style my elements. These two "layers" are positioned inside the app with "position: absolute; top: ..; left: ..." for the divs and "transform: translate(..,..)" for the JointJs models.

So far so good, everthing aligns perfectly while moving, scaling, resizing etc.
[image: Screenshot form the Application]

Now, when I select my div containing my graph to print, these elements now missalign by like a 8px shift.
[image: Label and icons are shifted up/left]

So far my theorie is this:
When printing the page, the page has a little border around the page, since printers wont print directly on the edge of a paper. This "margin" is respected by the svg, but not by the divs. Their origin seems to be the very top left corner of a page.

For the printing, I simply do this:

```js
function print() {
    const mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=650,width=900,top=100,left=150');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    for(let i=0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('paperContainer').length; i++) {
        const htmlElement = document.getElementsByClassName('paperContainer').item(i).outerHTML;
        mywindow.document.write(htmlElement);
    }
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-muf-c11="" class="paperContainer" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
    <div _ngcontent-muf-c11="" id="paper0" class="joint-paper joint-theme-default"
        style="background-color: white; width: 29cm; height: 20.5cm;">
        <div class="Server"
            style="position: absolute; width: 64px; height: 64px; left: 439px; top: 243px; transform: rotate(0deg); pointer-events: none; user-select: none; padding: 5px; box-sizing: border-box; z-index: 10;">
            <div class="iconPlaceholder">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 640 512" class="iconSize" width="64" height="64">
                    <g>
                        <path class="icon"
                            d="M480 160H32c-17.673 0-32-14.327-32-32V64c0-17.673 14.327-32 32-32h448c17.673 0 32 14.327 32 32v64c0 17.673-14.327 32-32 32zm-48-88c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24zm-64 0c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24zm112 248H32c-17.673 0-32-14.327-32-32v-64c0-17.673 14.327-32 32-32h448c17.673 0 32 14.327 32 32v64c0 17.673-14.327 32-32 32zm-48-88c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24zm-64 0c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24zm112 248H32c-17.673 0-32-14.327-32-32v-64c0-17.673 14.327-32 32-32h448c17.673 0 32 14.327 32 32v64c0 17.673-14.327 32-32 32zm-48-88c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24zm-64 0c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24z">
                        </path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <button class="delete"
                style="display: none; color: white; border: none; background-color: rgb(192, 57, 43); border-radius: 20px; width: 15px; height: 15px; font-size: 10px; position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 2px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto;">
                ✖
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="Server"
            style="position: absolute; width: 64px; height: 64px; left: 255px; top: 241px; transform: rotate(0deg); pointer-events: none; user-select: none; padding: 5px; box-sizing: border-box; z-index: 10;">
            <div class="iconPlaceholder">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 640 512" class="iconSize" width="64" height="64">
                    <g>
                        <path class="icon"
                            d="M480 160H32c-17.673 0-32-14.327-32-32V64c0-17.673 14.327-32 32-32h448c17.673 0 32 14.327 32 32v64c0 17.673-14.327 32-32 32zm-48-88c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24zm-64 0c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24zm112 248H32c-17.673 0-32-14.327-32-32v-64c0-17.673 14.327-32 32-32h448c17.673 0 32 14.327 32 32v64c0 17.673-14.327 32-32 32zm-48-88c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24zm-64 0c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24zm112 248H32c-17.673 0-32-14.327-32-32v-64c0-17.673 14.327-32 32-32h448c17.673 0 32 14.327 32 32v64c0 17.673-14.327 32-32 32zm-48-88c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24zm-64 0c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24s10.745 24 24 24 24-10.745 24-24-10.745-24-24-24z">
                        </path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <button class="delete"
                style="display: none; color: white; border: none; background-color: rgb(192, 57, 43); border-radius: 20px; width: 15px; height: 15px; font-size: 10px; position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 2px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto;">
                ✖
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="Zone"
            style="position: absolute; width: 338px; height: 208px; left: 203px; top: 174px; transform: rotate(0deg); pointer-events: none; user-select: none; padding: 5px; box-sizing: border-box; z-index: 5;">
            <button class="delete"
                style="display: none; color: white; border: none; background-color: rgb(192, 57, 43); border-radius: 20px; width: 15px; height: 15px; font-size: 10px; position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 2px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto;">
                ✖
            </button>
            <button class="resize"
                style="display: none; color: white; border: none; background-color: rgb(119, 119, 119); border-radius: 20px; width: 15px; height: 15px; font-size: 15px; position: absolute; bottom: 2px; right: 2px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto;">
                ⤡
            </button>
            <label
                style="font-size: 16px; position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px; outline: rgb(187, 187, 187) solid 1px; padding: 2px 4px;">Standard
                Sicherheit</label>
        </div>
        <div class="joint-paper-background" joint-selector="background"></div>
        <div class="joint-paper-grid" joint-selector="grid"></div>
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" joint-selector="svg" id="v-2">
            <defs joint-selector="defs">
                <marker id="v-21801458145" orient="auto" overflow="visible" markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                    <path id="v-31" stroke="#333333" fill="#333333" transform="rotate(180)" d="M 10 -5 0 0 10 5 z">
                    </path>
                </marker>
            </defs>
            <g joint-selector="layers" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" class="joint-layers">
                <g joint-selector="cells" class="joint-cells-layer joint-viewport">
                    <g model-id="a338dc1d-3d35-4a3c-97eb-9fbed0182d07" data-type="html.Element" id="j_3"
                        class="joint-cell joint-type-html joint-type-html-element joint-element joint-theme-default"
                        fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" transform="translate(203,174)">
                        <g class="rotatable" id="v-16">
                            <g class="scalable" transform="scale(3.38,3.466666666666667)">
                                <rect id="v-17" stroke="none" fill-opacity="1" fill="#cccccc" width="100" height="60">
                                </rect>
                            </g>
                            <text id="v-18" font-size="14" xml:space="preserve" display="none" y="0.8em" fill="#000000"
                                text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif"
                                transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,169,104)">
                                <tspan dy="0" style="fill-opacity: 0; stroke-opacity: 0;" class="v-line v-empty-line">-
                                </tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g model-id="3d03955b-d2f3-4a8a-bcc0-5b620a5f0b3f" data-type="html.Element" id="j_4"
                        class="joint-cell joint-type-html joint-type-html-element joint-element joint-theme-default"
                        fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" transform="translate(255,241)">
                        <g class="rotatable" id="v-19">
                            <g class="scalable" transform="scale(0.64,1.0666666666666667)">
                                <rect id="v-20" stroke="none" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff" width="100" height="60">
                                </rect>
                            </g>
                            <text id="v-21" font-size="14" xml:space="preserve" display="none" y="0.8em" fill="#000000"
                                text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif"
                                transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,32,32)">
                                <tspan dy="0" style="fill-opacity: 0; stroke-opacity: 0;" class="v-line v-empty-line">-
                                </tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g model-id="b95097d5-a0ac-4bc5-b8e4-c84022496ec0" data-type="html.Element" id="j_5"
                        class="joint-cell joint-type-html joint-type-html-element joint-element joint-theme-default"
                        fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" transform="translate(439,243)">
                        <g class="rotatable" id="v-22">
                            <g class="scalable" transform="scale(0.64,1.0666666666666667)">
                                <rect id="v-23" stroke="none" fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff" width="100" height="60">
                                </rect>
                            </g>
                            <text id="v-24" font-size="14" xml:space="preserve" display="none" y="0.8em" fill="#000000"
                                text-anchor="middle" font-family="Arial, helvetica, sans-serif"
                                transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,32,32)">
                                <tspan dy="0" style="fill-opacity: 0; stroke-opacity: 0;" class="v-line v-empty-line">-
                                </tspan>
                            </text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g model-id="d727a4a8-b968-42b5-a2c0-f4a63a9f533d" data-type="standard.Link" id="j_6"
                        class="joint-cell joint-type-standard joint-type-standard-link joint-link joint-theme-default">
                        <path fill="none" cursor="pointer" stroke="transparent" stroke-linecap="round"
                            joint-selector="wrapper" id="v-30" stroke-width="10" stroke-linejoin="round"
                            d="M 319 273 L 379 273 L 379 275 L 439 275"></path>
                        <path fill="none" pointer-events="none" joint-selector="line" id="v-29" stroke="#333333"
                            stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 319 273 L 379 273 L 379 275 L 439 275"
                            marker-end="url(#v-21801458145)"></path>
                        <g id="v-25" class="labels">
                            <g id="v-26" class="label" label-idx="0" cursor="default"
                                transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,379,274)">
                                <rect joint-selector="rect" id="v-28" fill="#ffffff" rx="3" ry="3" width="35.078125"
                                    height="31.015625" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-17.5,-15.5)"></rect>
                                <text joint-selector="text" id="v-27" font-size="14" xml:space="preserve" y="0.8em"
                                    fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" pointer-events="none"
                                    transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,-13.7)">
                                    <tspan dy="0" class="v-line">TCP&nbsp;</tspan>
                                    <tspan dy="1em" x="0" class="v-line">&nbsp;6543</tspan>
                                </text>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g joint-selector="tools" class="joint-tools-layer"></g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change my positioning of the divs from px to pt (like its suggested for printed content), but that didnt change anything.

I fear, that i have to shift every div down and right right before I print, but I feel like there must be a better option to get around this problem.

Since this is an Angular App, I dont know, if the created html is of any help to you, but I pasted the selected div for the print anyway.

Any ideas are apreciated. If you need more Information, let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED** ! (sort of)

I changed my print() function as followed:

```
print() {
      const mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=650,width=900,top=100,left=150');

      mywindow.document.write('<div style="position: absolute; top: 5pt; left: 5pt;">')
      for(let i=0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('paperContainer').length; i++) {
        const htmlElement = document.getElementsByClassName('paperContainer').item(i).outerHTML;
        mywindow.document.write(htmlElement);
      }
      mywindow.document.write('</div>')
      mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
      mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

      mywindow.print();
      mywindow.close();

    }
```

So I wrapped my content in a div with an absolute position and is itself shifted 5pt down and right. This only effects the div-elements and not the svgs. So now it's all alligned again.

This is not perfect and might break at other paper-formats, but in my case it fixes the issue.